# cannot find where a variable is used in a C++ source code

Tags: c++

I am beginning with C++, and I am studying the source code of the [HElib](https://github.com/shaih/HElib) library that I am going to work with.

In the file [Test_General.cpp](https://github.com/shaih/HElib/blob/master/src/Test_General.cpp) there is a variable `k` (the *"security parameter"* according to line 303).

**Question: Is this varibale unused in this file ?**

The function `void TestIt` line 57 takes `k` as parameter but I don't see any line where it uses it.
From my knowledge of the scheme it should be used during the setup phase, typically during the building of `context` line 79 or shortly after it.

Is it possible that this variable is used in this function while it is not noticeable in this file ?

Comment: It is not used. Why don't you ask the maintainer of that project about it?

Comment: @robert The maintainer are a small team and are dealing with many technical questions already. Since it was possible that this question was coming from my simple lack of knowledge about C++ I felt like asking on a general programming forum first. But if as you say it is unused then now I'm going to ask the developers why it is so.

Comment: Seeing as it's a testing function, I predict that the answer is "we haven't really got around to using it yet".

Comment: SO isn't a forum and I don't see how this is on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be used here:

```
TestIt(R, p, r, d, c, k, w, L, m, gens, ords);
```

Comment: Yes, however, that didn't answer the question. The OP said `k` appears to be unused *in the function*, not the file.

Answer (score 0):

It is used in `std::cerr` to form error message.

There is no rule that forces programmer to do something with variable, maybe it is just a flag that specifies something useful in error message.

Also it might be some backward compatibility. So function can be used with old code which passes 11 parameters and to be compatible with new-one that strictly specifies only 10 (but passes 11 anyway).

And there is a thing related to potential future problems, so `k` may be *reserved* variable and may become meaningful just in future (so for now you can pass anything).

It is hard to say because there may be a lot of different reasons, if you want truly right answer, you should contact person who wrote that code.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, it is used at line 349 to compute `m`:

```
long m = FindM(k, L, c, p, d, s, chosen_m, true);
```

then `m` is used to build the context at line 79:

```
FHEcontext context(m, p, r, gens1, ords1);
```

So everything is fine now. Sorry for the annoyance.